# How to insert data from a Form in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am new to React and I am trying to consume the data from a form component and use that data to call a function in another component called Fruits. For what i have read, I have to do it through props, but I am having trouble to actually do it.

I have a list of fruits and I want the user to be able to insert his favourite fruit. I have 3 components Form, Fruits, Fruit and App. I think that the best way to do this is to have a function addNewFruit() in the Fruits component, but I don't know how to send the data from the Form Component (stored in newFruit) to the Fruits Component.

here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import Fruits from "./Fruits";
import Form from "./Form";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of fruits</h1>
      <p>enter your favourite fruit</p>
      <Form />
      <Fruits />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FORM COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      rating: "",
    };
  }
  handlerName = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handlerRating = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      rating: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handlerSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newFruit = this.state;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handlerSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handlerName}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="rating"
            value={this.state.rating}
            onChange={this.handlerRating}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit fruit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

FRUITS COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Fruit from "./Fruit";
class Fruits extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruits: [
        { name: "Orange", rating: 6 },
        { name: "Banana", rating: 7 },
        { name: "Kiwi", rating: 9 },
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    const fruits = this.state.fruits.map((fruit) => (
      <Fruit name={fruit.name} rating={fruit.rating} />
    ));
    return fruits;
  }
}

export default Fruits;
```

FRUIT

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Fruit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {" "}
        The name of the fruit is {this.props.name} and its rating is{" "}
        {this.props.rating}
      </p>
    );
  }
}

export default Fruit;
```

Comment: to form to be able to call fruit you need to set a higher order function and pass it as a prop so when you execute it. fruit will listen to it and get either a value or a function call.

Comment: but I want to access the Form content in the fruits component, not the other way. And how can I access to that Form data without returning a <Form/> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to share data between 2 sibling components, you need to create a state, and a data handler function in a higher component. In this case, there should be a fruits state and a function to modify the state in the App component.

The state of fruits in App component is passed to Fruits component as a prop for display. The function in App component is passed to Form component as a prop to handle new fruit in the Form component.

The following snippet shows how it works.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruits: [
        { name: "Orange", rating: 6 },
        { name: "Banana", rating: 7 },
        { name: "Kiwi", rating: 9 },
      ],
    }

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleFormSubmit(newFruit) {
    const fruits = this.state.fruits;
    if (newFruit) {
      fruits.push(newFruit)
    }
    this.setState({
      fruits: fruits,
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>List of fruits</h1>
        <p>enter your favourite fruit</p>
        <Form formSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}/>
        <Fruits fruits={this.state.fruits}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      rating: "",
    };
  }
  handlerName = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handlerRating = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      rating: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  handlerSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newFruit = this.state;
    this.props.formSubmit(newFruit);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handlerSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handlerName}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="rating"
            value={this.state.rating}
            onChange={this.handlerRating}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit fruit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Fruits extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const fruits = this.props.fruits.map((fruit) => (
      <Fruit name={fruit.name} rating={fruit.rating} />
    ));
    return fruits;
  }
}

class Fruit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {" "}
        The name of the fruit is {this.props.name} and its rating is{" "}
        {this.props.rating}
      </p>
    );
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```